# LocationSettings request dialog appears again

Tags: android, kotlin, location, google-play-services

I am using google play services. For my application location is the key component. When `GPS` is off, I use `LocationSettingsClient` to show a dialog to the user to enable it. The problem is, After pressing `OK`, dialog appears again on some devices.

[image]

Here is my code for showing location settings:

**onResume**

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume")
        this.startLocationUpdates(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS, UPDATE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD)
    }

private fun startLocationUpdates(interval: Long, distance: Float = 0f) {
        if (!mSettingsClientInit)
            return

        createLocationRequest(interval, distance)
        createLocationCallback()
        // Begin by checking if the device has the necessary location settings.
        mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, object : OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse> {

                    override fun onSuccess(locationSettingsResponse: LocationSettingsResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "LocationManager: All location settings are satisfied.");
                        mLocationCallback?.let {
                            fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        }
//                        updateUI();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, object : OnFailureListener {
                    override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Request PErmission failure");
                        var statusCode = (e as ApiException).getStatusCode()
                        when (statusCode) {
                            LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                    // result in onActivityResult().
                                    var rae = e as ResolvableApiException;
                                    rae.startResolutionForResult(this@BaseLocationActivity, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                }
                            }
                            LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                )
    }
```

> Can anyone please point out why `LocationSettings` dialog is appearing
>   again and again on some devices, Not on all devices?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your **onCreate** instead of **onResume**. Because When dialog is dismiss activity's onResume is called. So your dialog appear again.

Comment: Why it is not happening on every device? Secondly, I have put logs, onResume log is not being shown.

Comment: Can you please check once ?

Comment: Actually, devices  that I have are not experiencing this issue. Users in the field are experiencing this. So, I cannot verify this fix on devices with me. The code in onResume is working fine on my device, this issue is not on every device, that's why I am curious that I should first reproduce and then try the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You put code in **onReSume**, so when you press OK, this code run again and the dialog appears again. You should put in **onCreate**, this code will run only one time when you run apps.

Comment: Thank you for response. Why it is not happening on every device? Same code is running on all devices.